# Do we need to synchronised, If we add through one thread and remove through other?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, thread-safety

In my app, i am receiving some points from my socket.io listener(thread 1)

Every time i do, i add them to the Queue, and i have a handler(another thread) running every x milliseconds to remove the first in value, and pass it to UI thread.

```
Queue<Integer> fifo = new LinkedList<>();

// socket.io background thread (THREAD 1)
new run() {
     Integer[] points = myapplication logic;      
     for (int point : points)
        fifo.add (point);
}
// handler background thread (THREAD 2) runs every few milliseconds
new run {
   Integer fiPoint = fifo.remove();
   // THREAD 3 (MAIN UI THREAD)
   runOnUIThread() {
      do something with that fipoint;
   }
}
```

Do i need to use Synchronised Queue, or my current implementation is fine ?

Answer (score 1):

Every method in `java.util.Stack` is already `synchronized`, so that would be perfectly safe. But you're using `Queue`, which is disastrous.

What happens if the reader thread can see that the object is in the queue but cannot see the internals of the object? That would cause a disaster.

Consider:

1. Writer thread marks that there is an object in the queue.
2. Reader thread sees that there is an object in the queue.
3. Reader thread access the object's member data.
4. Writer thread writes the object's member data.

Oops, the reader just saw the wrong data. You need to make sure all writes to the object have a "happens before" relationship to the reader thread being told the object is in the queue. Your code contains nothing that does that.

Comment: I may have msised soemthign but on my sources Stack#push isn't synchronised

Comment: That's because it's a [thin wrapper around a vector](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Stack.html) function which is synchronized.

Comment: I thought I was probably missing something if they bothered to synchronise everything else!

Comment: What should i be using than, I need FIFO ? Any java class thats has it inbuilt

Comment: You can use `java.util.Stack` or just use your own class that has all the functions `synchronized`.

Answer (score 1):

For the queue this is not safe - You can get a ConcurrentModificationException

```
0. fifo size(2)
1. Thread1 Calls fifo.push();
2. UI thread starts notify operation loping through 3 items
3. Thread2 Calls fifo.pop();
4. UI threads notify loop calls get(2) ... it's out of bounds
```

My suggestion:

```
Queue<Integer> fifo = new ArrayBlockingQueue();
```

You can read about it [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/ArrayBlockingQueue.html)

Comment: do you mean queue is not synchronized ?

Comment: Queue is just an interface, but unless he is using a BlockingQueue, it's not

Comment: @NickCardoso  What should i be using than, I need FIFO ? Any java class thats has it inbuilt.

Comment: ArrayBlockingQueue looks good (by that I mean: I haven't ever used it myself, but it supports your two requirements)

Answer (score 1):

Why would you even consider using a non-threadsafe class from multiple threads when you have a thread safe option available?   Are you concerned about performance?   Don't be. That is premature optimization.   Unless you have actually measured you the performance, and found it lacking, then don't even consider using Queue for this.

If Queue is not thread safe then you must NOT use it from more than one thread.

Why?
There are 2 problems.  **Atomicity** and **Visibility**.

Storing the integer in the Queue and removing from the queue are not guaranteed to be **atomic** operations. For example adding an item to the back of the Queue, would involve at least 2 steps.  Incrementing a counter with the number of objects in the array and then copying the bytes that represent a pointer to the new Integer into some kind of storage vessel.  In general you won't know what order that takes place and you don't care.  But what happens if you increment the count and before you can copy the reference some other thread takes over and reads from the Queue.  The count will say there is something there and it won't have been initialized yet.

Second, consider visibility.  When one thread modifies that counter, there is no guarantee that the change will be **visible** another thread at all, much less in a timely fashion.   Which means that one thread could be incrementing the variable and another could be incrementing it to the exact same value.   This could leave both your program and the Queue itself permanently broken.

Of course the writers of your implementation of Queue could work around all these issues.  If they do, they will tell you it is thread safe.  Sometimes they will say explicitly that it is NOT thread safe (e.g. HashMap).

I have used LinkingBlockingDeque when I didn't know how big my FIFO buffer needed to be.  And I have used ArrayBlockingQueue when I knew the buffer would not grow beyond a certain length.   I have never tested performance of the one over the over.